# Pandas check 2 datasets if values are less than x create new tables showing ture/false

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have 2 datasets, which I have put together below as examples

```
data1 = {
         'is10010': ['1.7', '1.21', '1.81', '1.89'],
         'is01010': ['1.23', '1.31', '1.77', '1.33'],
         'is11010': ['1.12', '1.51', '1.12', '1.79'],
         'is20010': ['1.2', '1.91', '1.02', '1.11'],
    }
data2 = {
         'is10010': ['1.17', '1.61', '1.81', '1.89'],
         'is01010': ['1.23', '1.31', '1.17', '1.33'],
         'is11010': ['1.12', '1.31', '1.12', '1.19'],
         'is20010': ['1.21', '1.71', '1.02', '1.21'],
    }
```

I would like to create a third dataset the holds true/false values if the following is matched or not.

```
If (dataset1 < 1.25) and (dataset2 < 1.43):
   dataset3 = true 
else:
  dataset3 = false
```

If following this with the above example then dataset 3 should look like the following

```
output = {
         'is10010': ['False', 'False', 'False', 'False'],
         'is01010': ['True', 'False', 'False', 'False'],
         'is11010': ['True', 'False', 'True', 'False'],
         'is20010': ['True', 'False', 'True', 'True'],
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert values of DataFrames to floats and compare both by chained by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(data1).astype(float)
dataset2 = pd.DataFrame(data2).astype(float)

out = (dataset1 < 1.25) & (dataset2 < 1.43)
print (out)
   is10010  is01010  is11010  is20010
0    False     True     True     True
1    False    False    False    False
2    False    False     True     True
3    False    False    False     True
```

Comment: I think that took me 10x longer to type up the question then it did for you to answer. Thanks it was me not adding astype in that was causing my confusion

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'is10010': ['1.7', '1.21', '1.81', '1.89'],
    'is01010': ['1.23', '1.31', '1.77', '1.33'],
    'is11010': ['1.12', '1.51', '1.12', '1.79'],
    'is20010': ['1.2', '1.91', '1.02', '1.11'],
}
data2 = {
    'is10010': ['1.17', '1.61', '1.81', '1.89'],
    'is01010': ['1.23', '1.31', '1.17', '1.33'],
    'is11010': ['1.12', '1.31', '1.12', '1.19'],
    'is20010': ['1.21', '1.71', '1.02', '1.21'],
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, dtype=float)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, dtype=float)

df3 = (df1 < 1.25) & (df2 < 1.43)
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
   is10010  is01010  is11010  is20010
0    False     True     True     True
1    False    False    False    False
2    False    False     True     True
3    False    False    False     True
```